# How to use If statement with a boolean function in another class

Tags: c++

I have a class EverTrueHelper.cpp.

```
bool EverTrueHelper::getAndReturnUserEntry(string userEntry)
{
    
    if (userEntry == "Q" || userEntry == "q")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;


    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I have these lines of code in my main function

```
cout << "Do you want to quit? Type 'Q' or 'q' else hit Enter" << endl;
cin >> userEntry;
if (getAndReturnUserEntry = true)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    continue;
}
```

I have an error on the "getAndReturnUserEntry" in my `if` statement. I can't quite figure out how to get around it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `=` operator, which is typically used for assignment, in the `if` statement `if (getAndReturnUserEntry = true)` instead of `==` operator, which is typically used for comparision? Also you forgot to call the function using `()` operator, didn't you?

Comment: "i have an error" - so [edit] to quote it...

Comment: Note: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can simply be `return condition;`

Answer (score 2):

You can call a method by using parentheses (`()`) and passing the argument(s) in them:

```cpp
cin >> userEntry;
if (getAndReturnUserEntry(userEntry))
{
    break;
}
else
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `continue;`.

Comment: @MikeCAT I omitted it because it wasn't pertinent to the point, but you're right, removing it is more confusing than having it. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problem with your `main` function's `if` statement:

- A single `=`, which means assignment, which is invalid in that case.
- You have not invoked `getAndReturnUserEntry`, add `()` at the end to actually invoke the function. After that, a test for `== true` is not necessary either since it will work anyway.

```cpp
cout << "Do you want to quit? Type 'Q' or 'q' else hit Enter" << endl;
cin >> userEntry;
if (getAndReturnUserEntry())
{
    break;
}
// continue program...
```

Further more, I think a better quit checking function will be:

```cpp
bool EverTrueHelper::getAndReturnUserEntry(string userEntry)
{
    return (userEntry == "Q" || userEntry == "q");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like follow:

```cpp
    cin >> userEntry;
    EverTrueHelper my_helper;
    if (my_helper.getAndReturnUserEntry(userEntry)) {
        break;
    }else{
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool EverTrueHelper::getAndReturnUserEntry(string userEntry)  {
    
    return ((userEntry == "Q" || userEntry == "q") ? true : false);
}



cout << "Do you want to quit? Type 'Q' or 'q' else hit Enter" << endl;
cin >> userEntry;
if (getAndReturnUserEntry(userEntry) == true)
    ; // break; doesn't make sense here
else
    ; // continue; doesn't make sense here
```